# Find Text without span Text - Python - Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, web

I want to get text that is stored on an element. Text is not a property instead when I expand Element (in chrome's inspection [DevTools]) it has two sub-properties, span and text. it looks something like this:
[image: Web Layout]
I want to find only the text property not span.

I've used several way like:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/HTML/Body/li/a")
text = elem.text
```

But this returns:

```
size
8
```

Copying the xpath for the property, copies "html\body\li\a.text()"
and finding this by xpath method throws error, obviously.

To the point: I just want to get text child property of element not span. But it returns both.
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Added a third approach also using document.evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span inside is usually used for styling so, getText Assumes all child elements are part of the actual text.

Couldn't find a  direct way to achieve what you are trying to do,

The workaround is to :

**First solution:**

just get the text from both and replace the unwanted part

```
 parent= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
 child= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')

 parentText= parent.text
 childText= child.text

 parentText=parentText.replace(childText, "")
```

**Else:**

**Second solution**

```
parent= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
parentText= driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent", parent)
```

parentText will have the value that you need

**Third approach :**

the script document.evaluate inside selenium execute script:

```
text= driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('//a/text()', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ).stringValue;");
```

text will have the required value